# Implementation of gaining experience in the game

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement such algorithm written by me:

```
// up to 2LVL (10) => 10 = 10 - 0 - 0
// up to 2LVL (5) => 5 = 10 - 0 - 5
// up to 3LVL (20) => 20 = 20 + (0+10) - 10
// up to 3LVL (15) => 15 = 20 + (0+10) - 15
// up to 3LVL (10) => 10 = 20 + (0+10) - 20
// up to 3LVL (5) => 5 = 20 + (0+10) - 25
// up to 4LVL (40) => 40 = 40 + (10+20) - 30
// up to 4LVL (35) => 35 = 40 + (10+20) - 35
// up to 4LVL (25) => 25 = 40+ (10+20) -45
// up to 4LVL (20) => 20 = 40 +(10+20) -50
// up to 4LVL (15) => 15 = 40+ (10+20) -55
```

here is a breach with other values

```
// up to 4LVL (10) => 10 = 40+ (10+20) -60
// up to 4LVL (5) => 5 = 40+ (10+20) -65
// up to 5LVL (80) => 80 = 80 +(10+20+40) -70
// up to 5LVL (75) => 75 = 80 +(10+20+40) -75
```

My implementation looks like this:

```
    int j = dbHelper.getExpRequirementsByLvl(cc.getLv() + 1) - dbHelper.getProfile().getExp();
    int k=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dbHelper.getProfile().getLvl()+1; i++)
        k = k+ dbHelper.getExpRequirementsByLvl(i);
    int m = j+k;
```

and it works until the loop reaches 4LVL. But why it doesn't work further?

I start the game and have 0exp. I kill one mob and get 5exp.Number in bracket on the left means how many exp we do need to get new level. Bracket on the right are numbers that means exp needed to lvl that we already gained.

The method looks like this:

```
    public int getExpRequirementsByLvl(int lvl) {
    int expRequired=0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from levels where lvl=" + lvl + "", null);

    if (res.moveToNext()) {
        expRequired = Integer.parseInt(res.getString(1));
    }

    return expRequired;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work further"? What goes wrong?

Comment: I mean the result of equation does not match the result in bracket

Comment: Can you give some examples of input, expected output, and actual output so that we can see the problem more clearly?

Comment: We have no idea what `getExpRequirementsByLvl()` does or returns, so we can't help you determine if the problem is in there or the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved,turned out the bug was in other place.